# Inner product exercise

Tags: real-analysis

Fix $n>0$. If $S_i>0$, then define $T:=\sum_{i=1}^n S_i
(\frac{i}{n})^{-t} $ where $0<t<s$.

If $\sum_{i=1}^k S_i \leq (\frac{k}{n})^s,\ 1\leq k\leq n$, then
  $T <C$ where $C$ is independent of $n$.

Proof : If $S=(S_1,\cdots, S_n),\ V=((
  \frac{1}{n})^{-t},\cdots, (
  \frac{i}{n})^{-t} ,\cdots, 1)$, then $S\cdot V\leq
  \|S\|_1\|V\|_\infty\leq n^t$.

How can we prove this ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_k := \sum_{i=1}^k S_i$ and $b_i := (i/n)^{-t}$. Using summation by parts, you have that
$$
T = \sum_{i=1}^n S_i b_i = A_n b_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i (b_i - b_{i+1})
\leq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^s
\left[\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{-t}-\left(\frac{i+1}{n}\right)^{-t}\right].
$$
Let us estimate the term $c_i$ of the last summation:
$$
0 < c_i = \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{s-t}
\left[1- \left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)^t\right]
\leq
\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{s-t} \frac{t}{i+1}
< t\, \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{s-t-1}\,.
$$
Let $\alpha := s-t-1$ (so that $\alpha > -1$).
We have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i \leq t \, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{\alpha}
\to t \int_0^1 x^{\alpha}\, dx = \frac{t}{1+\alpha},
$$
hence your sum is (asymptotically) estimated by $1+t/(s-t) = s/(s-t)$.